# How to get inserted row id after inserting row in room to the main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-room, android-architecture-components

I want to return the inserted row Id to use it to update some value in the same row

```
@Entity(tableName = "course")
public class Course {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String firebaseId;
}

@Dao
public interface CourseDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    long insertCourse(Course course);

    @Query("UPDATE course SET firebaseId = :firebaseId  WHERE id = :id")
     void updateFirebaseId(int id, String firebaseId);


}
```

the problem is I cant return the Id to the main thread

```
  public class Repository {
    private static final Object LOCK= new Object();
    private static Repository sInstance;
    private final CourseDao mCourseDao;
    private final AppExecutors mAppExecutors;



    public void insertCourse(final Course course) {
        mAppExecutors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCourseDao.insertCourse(course);
            }
        });
    }
    public void updateCourse(final Course course) {
        mAppExecutors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCourseDao.updateCourse(course);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

I tried to use liveData but its not supported on insert

```
Error:(34, 20) error: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List<Long>.
```

Is it possible to return the id of Course once the insertion is completed without writing a separate select query?

Comment: add some method to your activity or fragment, call it something like `void onInserted(long id)`, and call it when you have the ID, and want it in main thread. Just wrap it into `runOnUIThread`, or a `Handler`

Comment: I cant  `runOnUIThread ` because I don't want to 

 `allowMainThreadQueries` on the database.

I really don't know how to use `MutableLiveData<Long>`  I could not find clear example

Answer (score 4):

`LiveData` is not supported for `insert`.

I feel there are 2 approaches to do `insert` operation in the background thread and send the result (`long`) back to Activity:

1. Using `LiveData`, I personally like this approach:

   ```
   public class Repository {

       private LiveData<Long> insertedId = MutableLiveData()

       public void insertCourse(final Course course) {
           mAppExecutors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Long id = mCourseDao.insertCourse(course);
                   insertId.setValue(id);
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using `Rx`:

   ```
   return Single.fromCallable(() -> mCourseDao.insertCourse(course));
   ```

   Here, you'll get `Single<Long>` which you can observe in your `Activity`

Note: `Repository` will return `Long` to `ViewModel` and in your `ViewModel` will have the `LiveData` and `setValue` stuff.

Comment: if you are doing insertCourse() on a background thread then wouldn't you use "insertId.postValue(id)" not "insertId.setValue(id)"?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this in Java

In the environment where you want the id:

```
public class MyIdClass {

   ArrayList<Integer> someIds = new ArrayList<>(); //this could be a primitive it doesn't matter
```

constructor with repository....{}

```
   @FunctionalInterface   //desugaring... normal interfaces are ok I guess?
   public interface GetIdFromDao {
       void getId(long id);
   }

   public void insertSomething(
      Something something
   ) {
      someRepository.insertSomething(
         something,
         id -> someIds.add((int)id) //lambda replacement, I think method reference cannot be done because of (int) casting, but if Array is type long it could be done.
      );

   }

}
```

In **abstract class** MyDao...: (something that I cannot stress enough..., work with ABSTRACT CLASS DAO, its more flexible)

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
protected abstract long protectedInsertSomething(Something something);


public void insert(
        Something something,
        MyIdClass.GetIdFromDao getIdFromDao
) {
//get long id with insert method type long
    long newSomethingId = protectedInsertSomething(something);
    getIdFromDao.getId(newSomethingId);
}
```

Inside Repository, If you use `AsyncTask<X, Y, Z>`, you can actually pass everything through VarAgrs, even listeners, but be sure to recast them in the order which they get inserted, and use type Object or a common ancestor.

```
(Something) object[0];
(MyIdClass.GetIdFromDao) object[1];

new InsertAsyncTask<>(dao).execute(
   something, //0
   getIdFromDao  //1
)
```

Also use `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")`, nothing happens

Now If you want even further interaction, you can connect a LiveData to the listener, or construct a Factory ViewModel...
an abstract factory ViewModel... that would be interesting.
But I believe DataBinding has an Observable view Model which I guess can be used(?)... I really don't know.